# Can't use App Group Capability in Xcode with a .mobileprovision file

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning, appgroups

I am developing an App in SwiftUI for my thesis and I need the "App Group" capability to make my app and extension communicate. I don't have a Developer Account, I only have a .mobileprovision file that should give me access to the "App Group" capability. I checked the bundle identifier of the .mobileprovision and the bundle identifier of my app and it matches.
This file lets me create a container after adding the app group capability to my app (I could't do this without the .mobileprovision), but it shows me the container in red. I tried googling and it says to just refresh the containers, but when I try it I get an alerts that says: "*Communication with apple failed: you don't have permission to modify containers*".
I tried to ignore it and to continue activating it to see if I could solve this problem later on, but I can't even add the app groups to my extension and there is no way to add another bundle identifier that let's me access App Groups in my app.

In all the tutorials I saw they were using a Developer account that doesn't need any setup. The documentation is almost inexistent.

TO SUM IT UP:

- I have a .mobileprovision file that let's me create an app group;
- The app group is red and says that I don't have enough permissions;
- I can't add another bundle identifier for my extension in the .mobileprovision so I can't enable app groups in the extension.

So is there a way to enable app groups for an extension with a .mobileprovision file or I must need a Developer account? I am sorry I couldn't give any information on how the .mobileprovision file is created but it's created by my administrator and I can't see how it's done.

For the sake of clarity I'll add what I have in my .mobileprovision that should let me use app groups, don't know if it could help:

Entitlements

```
            <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
            <string>group.it.unisa.applefoundationprogram.Myapp</string>
    </array>
            
            <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>----------.it.unisa.applefoundationprogram.Myapp</string>
            
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
            <string>----------.*</string>
    </array>
            
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
            
            <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>----------</string>

</dict>
```